# Cloud Data Fusion triggered pipeline - reuse the already provisioned Dataproc clusters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-data-fusion

Is there a way to avoid the provisioning step for subsequently triggered outbound pipelines? It looks like when a pipeline triggers an outbound pipeline, it does the provisioning all over again. Can we simply execute the triggered pipeline on the provisioned cluster of the first?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Data Fusion has support for running a pipeline against an existing Dataproc cluster, see more details in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/running-against-existing-dataproc).